# Indefinite Integral

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I'm having problems with starting this integral, I'm not looking for the solution, but the first step/two would be appreciated.

**Integral**:

Evaluate

$$
\int dx \sqrt{x(4-x)}
$$

Comment: take $x$ as $4\sin^2y$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $ \displaystyle \int \sqrt{ 4 - 4 + 4x - x^2} dx$

$ =  \displaystyle \int \sqrt{ 2^2 - (x-2)^2}dx$

Now use the formula - $  \displaystyle \int \sqrt{a^2 - x^2} dx$

This should be enough

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Since $x(4-x)=4x-x^2=4-(x^2-4x+4)=2^2-(x-2)^2$ we can set $x-2=2\sin t$ so

$$\int\sqrt{x(4-x)}dx=\int 2\cos t(2\cos t)dt=4\int\cos^2 t dt$$

Answer (score 1):

Sub $x=4 \sin^2{t}$, $dx = 8 \sin{t} \cos{t} \, dt$, so the integral becomes

$$32 \int dt \sin^2{t} \cos^2{t} $$

That should be enough of a hint.

Comment: It seems that the OP is interested in Optic, since he wrote $dt$ before the integrand. +1

Comment: @BabakS.: heh.,that was my edit.